# Creating a Grammar that is equivalent to "RegEx A, RegEx B, or BOTH"

Tags: formal-grammars, regular-expressions

I have the following problem, create a Grammar on the Language {1,0} that accepts

> "strings with a length divisible by 3, **or** strings with a number of 0s divisible
>   by 3, **or** *BOTH*".

I created grammars for each part, but I'm not sure how to account for the "BOTH" clause.

I started by making a regular expression:

```
1*(01*01*01*)+|((0|1)(0|1)(0|1))+
```

Then I made the following Grammars for each of the two main parts:

```
1*(01*01*01*)+
```

becomes

```
S_1 -> 1F | F
F   -> 1F | 0G
G   -> 1G | 0H
H   -> 1H | 0M
M   -> F | (empty)
```

and

```
((0|1)(0|1)(0|1))+
```

becomes

```
S_2 -> 0C | 1C
C   -> 0D | 1D
D   -> 0E | 1E
E   -> S | (empty)
```

My question is, if I just use the central **or** in the regular expression and start the complete Grammar by branching to one of the two Grammars I made with no cross over*, will it somehow potentially compromise the "**or** *BOTH*" requirement in some cases? Or is that extra requirement just a red herring and will be *necessarily* satisfied by covering both of the base requirements? As far as I can tell, both are more or less completely independent of one another.

*ie just tack the two together with this at the start:

```
S -> S_1 | S_2
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S \to S_1 | S_2$

That is correct. A grammar doesn't care which derivation it used, or how many could have been used, as long as *at least one* derivation is valid.

Now if the question said *but not both*, then it would get complicated!